# Prevent user from manipulating folders from 'save file' dialog

Tags: c, windows, winapi, labwindows

I have an application in Labwindows that when a user clicks on a button, 'Save data', the button launches a file selection dialog box. For security reasons I want to disable the user from right clicking any where on the 'file selection dialog box' and being able to delete/rename existing files and/or create/delete existing folders/directories.

This can be done in windows with keyboard hook but thought there might be something easier in Labwindows. I have already tried setting the allowMakeDirectory attribute to 0 but this did nothing and the 'FileSelectPopupEx' function does not have an 'allowMakeDirectory' attribute to set.

I'm developing on windows7 and running the app on Vista.

Also for those who don't know most things that can be done in Windows, i.e. calls to strcpy,  GetLastError() and etc., can be called from LabWindows.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Neither the [Open and Save Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960.aspx) nor the [IFileDialog interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775966.aspx) provide the facilities you are looking for. Since your goal is to implement security, I would suggest having the OS enforce the restrictions by setting appropriate [ACLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374872.aspx) on the respective folders.

Comment: Or simply don't use the native OS dialogs.  Make your own dialog that exposes only the functionality you want.

Comment: Are you still working this problem?...